# Как на java с помощью graphics2d динамически рисовать элементы?

Tags: java, graphics

На данном примере я просто наследовал класс JPanel и переопределил метод paintComponent, подскажите пожалуйста как сюда добавить возможность ввести точку и чтобы она нарисовалась. Как добавить кнопку и поле ввода и получить от туда данные я знаю, но как сделать чтобы точки рисовались динамически в тот момент когда пользователь ввел новое значение и нажал кнопку? При этом остальные элементы не должны убираться.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
button.addActionListener(e -> // вешаем слушателя, который при нажатии на вашу кнопку будет что то делать
здесь зайдём что должно быть сделано

panel.repaint(); // вызываем у вашей панели метод перерисовки
);
```